# error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle with Dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to use @BindsInstance in a Component Builder, but can't inject dependency into a module

That is the component:

```kotlin
@Component(modules = [MainModule::class])
interface MainComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun mainDep(dep: MainTest): Builder

        fun build(): MainComponent
    }
}
```

That is the module:

```kotlin
@Module
class MainModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideMainTest(mainTest: MainTest) = mainTest
}
```

That is the class to inject:

```kotlin
interface MainTest {
    fun mainTest()
}

class MainTestImpl: MainTest {
    override fun mainTest() {
        println("main test")
    }
}
```

But when I try to inject it into MainActivity I get a compiler error

```
error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
public abstract interface MainComponent {
                ^
      com.example.testdagger.di.MainTest is injected at
          com.example.testdagger.di.MainModule.provideMainTest(mainTest)
      com.example.testdagger.di.MainTest is injected at
          com.example.testdagger.di.MainModule.provideMainTest(mainTest)
```

Comment: `provideMainTest` doesn't make sense, `@BindsInstance` adds dependency  (`MainTest`) in the dependency graph

Comment: @IR42 So, the main question is - How can I use that dependency later?
Should I inject somewhere that component?

Comment: Have you tried just injecting it wherever you need it? As @IR42 said, with `@BindsInstance` you're already providing the dependency to the component, so then you can use the component to inject it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to inject. I removed fun provideMainTest(mainTest: MainTest) = mainTest from the module and injected into MainActivity.
But wasn't initialized after the component inject

Comment: Please add the rest of the code. How you create the Component and how you inject the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and say what will happen like this:

```
    @BindsInstance
    fun mainDep(dep: MainTestImpl): Builder
```

and also:

```
@Module
class MainModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideMainTest(mainTestImpl: MainTestImpl): MainTest = mainTestImpl
}
```

I know that it is not exactly what you want to achieve, but I want to check the result. Also, please provide how you create the component and how do you inject the Activity.